# Display elements using Javascript EventListener

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

I'm making a visual novel in HTML and these are my HTML and JS codes for now.

HTML:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr><td width="650px" align = "justify"><p id = "firstp"></p></td></tr>
    <tr><td width="650px" align = "justify"><p id = "secondp"></p></td></tr>
</table>
<embed src="assets/Haze.mp3" hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="true"></embed>
```

JS:

```
    var i = 0;
    document.addEventListener("click", function(){
            if (i==1) { document.getElementById("secondp").innerHTML = "First Paragraph."; i=2;}
            if (i==0) { document.getElementById("firstp").innerHTML = "Second Paragraph."; i=1;}
        });
```

My questions:

1. Is it possible to display paragraphs without using `.innerHTML`?

Given the codes, when the user clicks his/her mouse, the paragraphs will display one by one. It worked. However, what I want is instead of writing the paragraph on the JS side, would it be possible to write it between the `<p>` and `</p>` tags and use the script to simply display the text? So, HTML should now look like this:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr><td width="650px" align = "justify"><p id = "firstp">First Paragraph</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td width="650px" align = "justify"><p id = "secondp">Second Paragraph</p></td></tr>
</table>
```

How should the JS change such that it could still display the paragraphs one by one whenever the user clicks his/her mouse?

2. How to apply #1 method on displaying other elements (i.e. buttons, links, pictures)?

It's just the same as in number 1 but instead of a paragraph, it will display the button/link/picture when user clicks his/her mouse. I'm not referring to the `onclick` event. I'm still referring to `EventListener`.

3. How to change background music (`embed`) when mouse is clicked? Or keep the music playing even when player/user progressed to the next scene (meaning different HTML)?

I thought of putting the music outside the `iframe` just to loop the music. But I figured doing so would be useless, because what if in the next scene, I want to use a different background music. Or is it possible for the HTML within the `iframe` to trigger and change the music playing outside the `iframe`?

Answer (score 0):

try using JQuery, also add some class name(e.g `class1`) then load the below script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.class1').hide();
    $('.class1').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $('.class2').click(function(){
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
});
```

here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/57gf5m9m/7/)

Comment: What if there's no button? Paragraph will show when user clicks his/her mouse. Is there an equivalent `EventListener` to `JQuery`?

Answer (score 0):

try using this:**EDITED**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1">
    <tr><td width="650px" align = "justify"><p id = "firstp">First Paragraph</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td width="650px" align = "justify"><p id = "secondp">Second Paragraph</p></td></tr>
</table>


<div id="music">
    <embed type="audio/mpeg" src="#" name="plugin" height="100%" width="100%" id="mplayer">
</div>  
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#firstp").hide();
    $("#secondp").hide();
    var i = 0;
var songs = [];
songs[0] = "/XXXX/../assets/Hangover - DownloadMing.SE.mp3";// full path to your songs if the are not in current directory
songs[1] = "/XXXX/../assets/Tu Hi Tu - DownloadMing.SE.mp3";
    document.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if (i==1) { $("#secondp").show();}
        if (i==0) { $("#firstp").show(); i = 1;}
  $('#mplayer').attr('src',songs[j%2]);
j++;
    });

  });  
  </script>
```

**note:** For buttons also you can create them on your page and with the button id hide them and show them on addEventListener of click.

Comment: I followed what you said. It didn't work. The paragraphs displayed automatically. Also, will this work even without internet connection?

Comment: Okay, never mind. It worked, but I kind of have to put `$(document).ready(function()` as answered by mido22 below. Btw, can I also ask something about that part regarding embed? Thank you.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ }); this means when the page in ready i.e. loaded properly.It wont work without internet.to make it work without internet you have to download the latest jquery.min.js file from jquery site and place it in your project,and the use on pages where you need.

Comment: Can I ask what the `id` for `div` is for? I hid the player and set it to autostart and loop but no music played. Also, correct me if I'm wrong, the `.attr` will supposedly allow me to change the music right? So, if I want to change the background music, I'd just have to change the location of the file?

Comment: the div id is only to use for hiding and showing that's all and you are write .attr is to set the src on each click or may be the way you want to implement.

Comment: i have added the song change on click also and it is working for me try it out.

Comment: I tried it out. It still didn't work. I'll just post the code here so that you can check where I did wrong. I have this between the `<div>` tags as you inputted above: `<embed type="audio/mpeg" src="#" name="plugin" id="mplayer" hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="true">`. Then, on the JS side, I have this: `$("#mplayer").attr("src", "assets/Music1.mp3");` and this other `if (i==6) { $("#mplayer").attr("src", "assets/Music2.mp3");}` under the `addEventListener`.

Comment: try /assets/Music2.mp3 instead of assets/Music2.mp3

Comment: if the above is not working then to check first put the songs in the directory where your html is then use the way i have used.

Comment: please use total path like /your project name/../assets/Music2.mp3.

Comment: I also tried that. I still got nothing. I even tried experimenting and removed `<div>`. I got nothing.